Limit NetSuite Saved Search Results
I want to limit the results of a Saved Search in NetSuite to the first 100 rows.
I've tried creating a Result field of 'Formula (Numeric)' with the formula '{rownum} <= 100' as suggested by several online pages, but {rownum} isn't even one of the options in the formula popup, so it throws errors.
Checking 'Run Unrestricted' and specifying 'Max Results' doesn't work either – it returns every matching row.
What is the saved search equivalent of SQL's 'LIMIT' keyword?

Can you say more about why you are wanting to have this limit? What is the context in which you are using the results?

rownum is not a field. It is built-in so your Formula (Numeric) clause would just be
rownum

not
{rownum}

